# selenium chrome not logging

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to debug something on selenium and trying to enable the logging for it, but for some reason its not logging, i have the following options enabled for it

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-cache')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-path=/var/tmp/chrome.log')
chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
```

Is there something missing that its not logging to chrome.log?